Can I create variables in terragrunt based on the dependencies outputs?
Let us assume we have a terragrunt.hcl file that looks like this
terraform {
  source = "${dirname(find_in_parent_folders(".root"))}/terraform/modules/cloudwatch-alarms"
}

dependency "ec2-instance" {
  config_path = "../instance"
}

include "root" {
  path   = find_in_parent_folders()
  expose = true
}

locals {
  alerts_sns_topic_arn = "arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:secret:alerts"
}

inputs = {
  alarms = {
    "high-cpu-notify" = {
      alarm_name          = "awsec2-${dependency.ec2-instance.outputs.tags_all["Name"]}-CPUUtilization-Notify"
      namespace           = "AWS/EC2"
      metric_name         = "CPUUtilization"
      comparison_operator = "GreaterThanThreshold"
      evaluation_periods  = "1"
      period              = "300"
      statistic           = "Average"
      threshold           = "20"
      alarm_actions = [
        local.alerts_sns_topic_arn,
      ]

      dimensions = {
        InstanceId = dependency.ec2-instance.outputs.id
      }
    },
    "cpu-very-high-notify" = {
      alarm_name          = "awsec2-${dependency.ec2-instance.outputs.tags_all["Name"]}-CPUUtilization-Restart"
      namespace           = "AWS/EC2"
      metric_name         = "CPUUtilization"
      comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
      evaluation_periods  = "1"
      period              = "300"
      statistic           = "Average"
      threshold           = "60"
      alarm_actions = [
        local.alerts_sns_topic_arn,        
      ]

      dimensions = {
        InstanceId = dependency.ec2-instance.outputs.id
      }
    },
  }
}


I am creating 2 cloudwatch alerts with a custom terraform module that I created.
I am reusing this variable ${dependency.ec2-instance.outputs.tags_all["Name"]} coming from the dependency in the 2 alarms for defining the alarm_name input.
My question is:
Is it possible to create a variable in terragrunt that uses the dependencies outputs and reuse it while defining the inputs ?
I tried the following without success

Defining a new variable into the locals like identifier = "${dependency.ec2-instance.outputs.tags_all["Name"]}-someotherstuff" This gave error that you cannot use dependencies inside locals block
Doing the same thing as above but within the inputs block and then trying to use that variable like ${inputs.identifier}. This didn't work and got error no variable inputs exist


There is a workaround that I have seen previously. You can have a file deps.hcl.
dependency "ec2-instance" {
  config_path = "../instance"
}

Then in your terragrunt.hcl:
terraform {
  source = "${dirname(find_in_parent_folders(".root"))}/terraform/modules/cloudwatch-alarms"
}
    
dependency "ec2-instance" {
  config_path = "../instance"
}
    
include "root" {
  path   = find_in_parent_folders()
  expose = true
}
    
locals {
  alerts_sns_topic_arn = "arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:secret:alerts"
  deps = read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("deps.hcl"))
  identifier = local.deps.dependency.ec2-instance.outputs.tags_all["Name"]
}


hm.. so you create another file deps.hcl only with the dependency and nothing else, and import it into locals with read_terragrunt_config right? I have to try it

yes, it should be found by find_in_parent_folders

I don't like this solution but as there are no other options accepted it as answer. Did not use it though, I just repeated the long concat everywhere needed
